# How to work with Bootstrap 3 glyphicons and Oracle Application Express

Tags: oracle, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, oracle-apex, glyphicons

How can I manage to use Bootstrap 3 glyphicons in APEX? I uploaded all Bootstrap files in the Share Components (Cascading Style Sheets) but when I try to display a glyphicon, it seems like it cannot find the font.

This is the code to display the gryphicon:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the link to the font files in the bootstrap.css file.

Edit the bootstrap.css file. Search for `@font-face` in the file and fix the font file location references for the src attributes:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  ...
}
```

Please note that you can’t use substitution strings in workspace or application files. If you want to do so, move the CSS rule to your page template(s) (or in the page attributes) as inline CSS.

Comment: Indeed a common problem when trying to use css or js files stored in the workspace!

Comment: Spot on. I was after a solution to this. Didn't think of using inline CSS in the page. +1